# $\lim S_n$ finite implies $\sum E(X_n)$ finite

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

I am learning Second Borel-Cantelli Lemma now and come across a problem.

If $X_n \in [0,1]\forall n$,$S_n=\sum^n_{i=1}X_i$,$X_i$ independent and $\lim S_n<\infty$, then $\sum EX_n$ is finite.

The question gives a hint:

$$e^{-x}\leq 1-ax\leq e^{-ax},\forall x\in [0,1]\;\text{where} \; a=1-e^{-1}$$

and try to use product rule for expectation.

The hint seems to suggest us to go through the proof of Second Borel -Cantelli but I really don't get it.

I tried to plug the $X_n$ into the inequality but it leads me nowhere.  I also tried to see $E(e^{-S_n})$ and use the product rule but still fails.

Something obvious am I missing?

Comment: What about $X_n \equiv 1/n$?

Comment: @PhoemueX, thanks for reply! I think $S_n$ would go to $\infty$ in this case.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I misread your assumptions :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We want to show $\lim_n ES_n<\infty$, which is equivalent to showing \begin{equation}\tag{$\star$}\lim_n e^{-aES_n}>0\qquad\end{equation} We have that
$$
e^{-aES_n}=\prod e^{-aEX_i}\ge \prod(1-aEX_i)=E\left(\prod (1-aX_i)\right)\ge E\left(\prod e^{-X_i}\right)=E(e^{-S_n})
$$
Taking the limit of both sides (which exists by monotonicty)
\begin{equation}\tag1
\lim_n e^{-aES_n}\ge \lim_n E(e^{-S_n})
\end{equation}
Now, using Fatou's Lemma, we get
\begin{equation}\tag2
\lim_n E(e^{-S_n})\ge E(\lim_n e^{-S_n})=E(e^{-\lim_n S_n})
\end{equation}
Again, we can use lim instead of liminf since all limits in question exist.

Now, since $\lim_n S_n<\infty$ almost surely, this means that $e^{-\lim S_n}>0$ a.s, proving that $Ee^{-\lim_n S_n}>0$:
\begin{equation}\tag3
E( e^{-\lim_n S_n})>0
\end{equation}
Combining (1),(2), and (3) proves $(\star)$, as desired.

Comment: Thank you, @Mike Earnest! I got trouble with a  problem concerning  converge in probability, you may take a look if you have time.http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1155325/lim-sup-z-n-leq-alpha-ez-n-geq-alpha-z-n-leq-b-implies-z-n-rightarrow

Comment: So your proof actually establishes the (stronger) claim that if $\lim_n S_n$ is finite with positive probability, then $\sum_n E(X_n) = \lim E(S_n)$ is finite. Nice!

Comment: True. However, using Kolmogorovs 0-1 law, you can show $P(\lim S_n<\infty)>0$ implies $P(\lim S_n<\infty)=1$, so the fact that you only need this weaker assumption becomes less surprising.