# $\lim\sup Z_n\leq \alpha , EZ_n\geq \alpha,|Z_n|\leq B \implies Z_n\rightarrow \alpha$ in probability

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence

I come across a problem about converge in probability. The problem asks to prove the following:

$$\lim\sup Z_n\leq \alpha , EZ_n\geq \alpha ,|Z_n|\leq B \implies Z_n\rightarrow \alpha\;\text{ in probability}$$

where $Z_n$ is real random variables (not necessarily independent) and $\alpha,B\in \mathbb{R}$.

I think it should be an easy problem but I really got trouble in proving this.

So far, I could see $\lim\sup Z_n =\alpha$  ,$\lim E(Z_n)=\alpha$ by $\alpha \geq E(\lim\sup Z_n)\geq \limsup EZ_n \geq \alpha $ .

How should I link the expectation with the probability in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to show $P(Z_n>\alpha+\epsilon)\to 0$ and $P(Z_n<\alpha-\epsilon)\to 0$.

The first follows since $\limsup Z_n\le \alpha$, proving $P(Z_n>\alpha+\epsilon\text{ i.o.})=0$.

Using $\lim_n EZ_n=\alpha$, given $\delta>0$, choose $n$ large enough so $E(Z_n-\alpha)>-\delta$. Let $X^+$ denote $\max(X,0)$, $X^-=\max(-X,0)$. Then $E(Z_n-\alpha)^+ - E(Z_n-\alpha)^-=E(Z_n-\alpha)>-\delta$, so
$$
E(Z_n-\alpha)^-\le E(Z_n-\alpha)^++\delta
$$
Combine these with the bounds
$$
\epsilon P(Z_n<\alpha-\epsilon)\le E(Z_n-\alpha)^-
$$
$$
E(Z_n-\alpha)^+\le\delta\cdot P(0<Z_n-\alpha<\delta)+B\cdot P(Z_n-\alpha>\delta)\le \delta+B\cdot P(Z_n-\alpha>\delta)
$$
to get
$$
P(Z_n<\alpha-\epsilon)\le \frac1{\epsilon}(2\delta+B\cdot P(Z_n-\alpha>\delta))
$$
Letting $n\to\infty$ shows $\limsup_n P(Z_n<\alpha-\epsilon)\le \frac{2\delta}{\epsilon}$. This holds for all $\delta>0$, proving $\limsup_n P(Z_n<\alpha-\epsilon)=0$.

Comment: Thanks, @Mike Earnest! I guess $E(Z_n-\alpha)^+$ approaches zero is the really essential part and then you can use Markov inequality to $P(|Z_n-\alpha|\geq \epsilon)\leq E|Z_n-\alpha|/\epsilon$.